# ng2-chart Angular: doughnut [plugins] isen't a know property of 'canvas' TEXT CENTER

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2019, ng2-charts

[image: Text]
[image: Text]

> angular core 5.1.6 ng2-chart 1.6.0 visual studio 2019 community.. 
>   the code works in stack-blitz as seen in picture.  but it complains
>   about plugins.. when I copy it to my project.  if I remove the
>   Plugins it works.. but no text in center.  is there another way to
>   get text in center that does not use plugins

in otherwords want to run this code TYPESCRIPT
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the plugin in the options, then you don't need to use the attribute in HTML. I'm using the `pluginDataLabels` to show my labels.

```
chartOptions: ChartOptions = {
...
plugins: {
   pluginDataLabels
};
```

It doesn't even matter where to put the pluginDataLabels in my example. It will show in every Chart. If you want to avoid that, you can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622806/how-to-import-chart-js-chartjs-plugin-datalabels-npm-package-into-an-angular-7-p/57922660#57922660).

Comment: "its the 350 download sales" that not working , I have hover over labels to show data.